# How do I refactor my work without using global variables?

Tags: python

I currently have a working solution for part of a project I'm working on. However, it's been quite tough to find ways to make things work the way I would like without using global variables.

I've replicated my work as follow:

```py
x_age = ''
x_name = ''

def find_info(x, y):
    global x_age
    global x_name
    x = 'Joseph'
    y = '23'
    x_name = x
    x_age = y

def main():
    find_info(x_name, x_age)
    print('name is ' + x_name)
    print('age is ' + x_age)

main()
```

My goal is to pass the assignments made inside `find_info()` back to their corresponding variable (`x_name && x_age`)

A work-around I found looks like this:

```py
def find_info():
    x = 'Joseph'
    y = '23'
    return x, y

def main():
    x_name, x_age = find_info()
    print('name is ' + x_name)
    print('age is ' + x_age)

main()
```

To use this solution would imply refactoring many other parts of my code and I would rather not if I can help it. So I'm looking for some guidelines on how to achieve the result I'm looking for (described above) without using `global` while also passing `x_name && x_age` to `find_info()`.

Comment: so you want to modify a global variable but don't want to use `global`, that'd be the easiest, other is to pass by reference, making a static class or an object to store that variable, then passing that object around functions would modify the value everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you know OOP? if not you should learn it. It becomes easier that way.

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self,name="",age=""):
    self.name=name
    self.age=age

def find_info(obj):
    x = 'Joseph'
    y = '23'
    obj.name = x
    obj.age = y

def main():
    x=Person()
    find_info(x)
    print('name is ' + x.name)
    print('age is ' + x.age)
```

Here, you can reuse the Person class as many time as you want, like:

```py
y=Person('me','18')
print("name:",y.name) #prints name:me
```

or better, you can define a method of Person class. and you can do `x.find_info()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actually work, doing OOP with classes might be a solution. I'd not suggest to use classes unless you're going to manipulate the data that is hold in the class within the class.

For a simple data container, a dict might be a better solution and is IMHO a more pythonic approach.

```
$ cat foo.py
def find_info(person):
    person['name'] = 'Joseph'
    person['age'] = 42

def main():
    person = { 'name': 'John', 'age': 42 }
    print(f'person before calling find_info(): {person}')
    find_info(person)
    print(f'person after calling find_info(): {person}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This results in:

```
$ python foo.py
person before calling find_info(): {'name': 'John', 'age': 42}
person after calling find_info(): {'name': 'Joseph', 'age': 42}
```

Other data structures, such as NamedTuples might be even more handy than that. It all depends on what you want to do.

One thing is for sure: You don't need globals here.